# iteration associated object js

Tags: javascript, object, iteration

i want to use `Symbol.iterator` in object for iteration associated object

i need to return all key and all value in loop

**this is my output :**

```js
let price = {
    money:2000,
    edit_photo:{
        yes:100,
        no:0
    },
    photo_type:{
        personal:300,
        sport:400,
        fashion:500,
        commercial:600
    },
    [Symbol.iterator](){
        let items = Object.keys(this);
        let step = 0;
        return{
            next(){
                let object = {
                    done: step >= items.length,
                    value: items[step]
                }
                step++;
                return object;
            }
        }
    }
}
for (let item of price) {
    console.log(item)
}
```

i have a problem to scroll all value

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here? What is the behavior of your attempted code? And what do you want it to be instead?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i need to return all key and value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You formed your `Symbol.iterator` incorrectly. The `Symbol.iterator` is technically a `generator` and not an iterator. A `generator` function needs to be marked with a `*`.

```js
const someObj = {
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    yield 'a';
    yield 'b';
  }
}
```

That way your object knows to actually use it as a `generator` function.

Now that we're using the right type of function, we have to return the right type of value. Well, `yield` the right type of value.

Since you are looking to return the `key` and `value` for each object item, the object we're `yield`ing might looks like this:

```js
yield {
  done: false,
  key: items[step],
  value: this[items[step]]
}
```

To make sure we yield each item of the object, we put this inside of a while loop.

```js
while (steps < items.length) {
  yield { /* ... */ };
  step++;
}
```

Once the `while` loop exits, we yield our final object.

```js
yield {
  done: true,
  value: this,
};
```

The complete code based on your example is below. Citing my source: MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator).

```js
let price = {
  money:2000,
  edit_photo:{
    yes:100,
    no:0
  },
  photo_type:{
    personal:300,
    sport:400,
    fashion:500,
    commercial:600
  },
  *[Symbol.iterator](){
    let items = Object.keys(this);
    let step = 0;
    while (step < items.length) {
      yield {
        done: false,
        key: items[step],
        value: this[items[step]]
      };
      step++;
    }
    yield {
      done: true,
      value: this,
    }
  }
}

for (let item of price) {
  console.log(item);
}
```